# ethereum transaction hash is not showing any result on ropsten ether scan.. here is my code and transaction hash. any suggestion?

Tags: transactions

```
var web3 = new Web3('');
    var contractData =[];
    //var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
    var account1 = sendFrom;
    var account2 = sendTo;
    var PRIVATE_KEY_ACCOUNT_1=PriKey; //from private key
    var PRIVATE_KEY_ACCOUNT_2 =ToPkey; //sender private key
    var contract_address_ac1 =conAdd;

var txCount = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1)

var smartContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractData,contract_address_ac1)
var gas = web3.eth.getGasPrice(function(error, result){
console.log(result);
});
    // Transaction
     var txObject = {
        nonce:    web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
        to:       account2,

    //value:    web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether')),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(8000000),
   // gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1000000000', 'gwei')),
    data:smartContract.methods.transfer(account2,token).encodeABI(),
 }

// Sign the transaction
var tx = new ethereumjs.Tx(txObject, { chain: 'ropsten', hardfork: 'istanbul' })
var pk = new ethereumjs.Buffer.Buffer.from(PRIVATE_KEY_ACCOUNT_1, 'hex')
tx.sign(pk)

var serializedTx = tx.serialize()
var raw =  '0x'+ serializedTx.toString('hex')

 // Broadcast the transaction
 web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw,function(err,receipt){
    //console.log(err)
    //console.log(receipt)
    $('.Hash').html("Transaction Hash: "+receipt);
    $('.error').html(err);
})
```

transaction hash: //0xc08296ba5c5fa5e68accdae6a2ed8bc21a7c6030091c785ea0339fa965ae88a3
//0x755c1a767fb13223705165bbd6fd2383f8f941d56cb1d8f7c28eddf54ffb4c74

Comment: Hello. Please explain what is your expected output, what seems to go wrong and what you have tried so far.

Comment: transaction hash is not showing any result on ropsten ether scan .. hash : 0xc08296ba5c5fa5e68accdae6a2ed8bc21a7c6030091c785ea0339fa965ae88a3

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question here.

Comment: How did you connect to ropsten, infura, metamask, own node? Some causes of failure, your node isn't synchronized, your account doesn't have enough funds, nonce was wrongly calculated.

Comment: connect with ifura ropsten test network(https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxx)' ... as you can see, i share my complete code above... i'm using web3 1.2.6 and ethereumjs-tx-1.3.3 ..